# How can I break out of an infinite loop in Excel 2011 for OS X?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel

I am working on Excel macros on OS X. I am fairly new to Excel, so I commonly encounter infinite loops.

How can I interrupt a running macro subroutine without killing the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Visual Basic Editor, if this is happening to you a lot, get in the habit of creating a counter inside your loop that increments on each loop and set a Watch that Breaks when it changes value, or reaches a value.

Setting a Break point somewhere such as the Next, or Do Loop will at least enable you not kill things completely.

Also the Break key is triggered with the [apple]+[.] *the apple
button along with the period button combination*, but always setting up a way out of the loop should be your practice until you have debugged thoroughly